# Drawing a graph with confidence intervals

Tags: graph, line, stata

Below is a sample of my data:

```
clear

input year mean1 ci5 ci95    
1991 0.398 0.351 0.444
1992 0.800 0.739 0.860
1993 0.429 0.408 0.450
1994 0.653 0.591 0.715
1995 0.312 0.278 0.346
1996 0.187 0.157 0.217
1997 0.149 0.126 0.172
1998 0.275 0.219 0.331
1999 0.178 0.148 0.207
2000 0.102 0.080 0.123
end
```

How can I draw a line in Stata with `year` on x-axis and `mean1` on y-axis?

I would also like to include the confidence intervals.

Comment: You should at least try some code.

Answer (score 3):

```
twoway rcap ci5 ci95 year || connected mean1 year
```

You can use `line` not `connected`, naturally.